# how to submit youtube comment through youtube API

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-api

I am retriving a youtube video's comment using youtube API. also i have created a sample input box where user will type a comment and he will submit it.

So my question is .. Is it possible to submit a comment using Youtube API. If yes then how ??

Please explain via sample code

I am using Core Javascript and html

I got following tutorial but POST method is not working .. [API link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube api 2.0 is deprecated, you can reply a comment using G+ Pages api, but it's only for partners at this time (https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup)